# Connect to Memorystore from Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I want to run a service on Google Cloud Run that uses Cloud Memorystore as cache.

I created an Memorystore instance in the same region as  Cloud Run and used the example code to connect: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/memorystore/redis/main.go this didn't work.

Next I created a Serverless VPC access Connectore which didn't help. I use Cloud Run without a GKE Cluster so I can't change any configuration.

Is there a way to connect from Cloud Run to Memorystore?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To connect Cloud Run (fully managed) to Memorystore you need to use the mechanism called "Serverless VPC Access" or a "VPC Connector".

As of May 2020, Cloud Run (fully managed) has Beta support for the Serverless VPC Access. See [Connecting to a VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) for more information.

Alternatives to using this Beta include:

- Use [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke), where [GKE provides the capability](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-cluster) to connect to Memorystore if the cluster is configured for it.
- Stay within fully managed Serverless but use a GA version of the Serverless VPC Access feature by using [App Engine with Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-memorystore).

Comment: Are there any updates on this VPC Connector support feature? (Oct 2019)

Comment: Not yet, I will update when something is announced.

Comment: So there is no way to use Memorystore on Cloud Run? :/

Comment: @Grayside Any rough ETA when we can expect this support to be available?

Comment: This just reached beta out ahead of the documentation. Once the docs are out I'll update the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm (although you need to pay for Serverless VPC Access).

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for [serverless VPC connectors on Cloud Run](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132922075) - Google said yesterday that announcements would be made in the near term - you can connect to Memorystore from Cloud Run using an SSH tunnel via GCE.

The basic approach is the following.

**First, create a forwarder instance on GCE**

```
gcloud compute instances create vpc-forwarder --machine-type=f1-micro --zone=us-central1-a
```

Don't forget to open port 22 in your firewall policies (it's open by default).

**Then install the gcloud CLI via your Dockerfile**

Here is an example for a Rails app. The Dockerfile makes use of a script for the entrypoint.

```docker
# Use the official lightweight Ruby image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby
FROM ruby:2.5.5

# Install gcloud
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin

# Generate SSH key to be used by the SSH tunnel (see entrypoint.sh)
RUN mkdir -p /home/.ssh && ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/.ssh/google_compute_engine -q -N ""

# Install bundler
RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler

# Install production dependencies.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
ENV BUNDLE_FROZEN=true
RUN bundle install

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Finally open an SSH tunnel to Redis in your entrypoint.sh script**

```bash
# !/bin/bash

# Memorystore config
MEMORYSTORE_IP=10.0.0.5
MEMORYSTORE_REMOTE_PORT=6379
MEMORYSTORE_LOCAL_PORT=6379

# Forwarder config
FORWARDER_ID=vpc-forwarder
FORWARDER_ZONE=us-central1-a

# Start tunnel to Redis Memorystore in background
gcloud compute ssh \
  --zone=${FORWARDER_ZONE} \
  --ssh-flag="-N -L ${MEMORYSTORE_LOCAL_PORT}:${MEMORYSTORE_IP}:${MEMORYSTORE_REMOTE_PORT}" \
  ${FORWARDER_ID} &

# Run migrations and start Puma
bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec puma -p 8080
```

With the solution above Memorystore will be available to your application on `localhost:6379`.

**There are a few caveats though**

1. This approach requires the service account configured on your Cloud Run service to have the `roles/compute.instanceAdmin` role, which is quite powerful.
2. The SSH keys are backed into the image to speedup container boot time. That's not ideal.
3. There is no failover if your forwarder crashes.

I've written a longer and more elaborated approach in a [blog post](https://www.keypup.io/post/connecting-to-memorystore-from-cloud-run) that improves the overall security and adds failover capabilities. The solution uses plain SSH instead of the `gcloud` CLI.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something in your VPC, you can also spin up [Redis on Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/redis?_ga=2.171558112.-1527459705.1556231760)

It's more costly (especially for a Cluster) than Redis Cloud - but an temp solution if you have to keep the data in your VPC.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since Google Cloud Run containers cannot (yet) connect to a VPC, I don't see how this would help in this case.