# GCP: connect to Memotystore from cloud run Django app?

Tags: django, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-memorystore

I'd like to add cache to my Django app hosting on Cloud Run.

From Django [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache), we can connect Django to a memory-based cache. Since I'm using Cloud Run, the memory get cleaned.

Memotystore seems good for this purpose, but there's only [tutorial for flask and redis](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run#python).

How could I achieve this?

Or should I just use a database caching?

Answer (score 0):

- Connect Redis instance to Cloud Run service using the steps in
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run#python).
- To connect from Cloud Run (fully managed) to Memorystore you need to
  use the mechanism called **"Serverless VPC Access" or a "VPC
  Connector"**
- First, you have to create a [Serverless VPC Access    Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector)
  and then configure [Cloud Run to use this connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#cloud-run)
- See [connecting to a VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) for more information.

Alternatives to using this include:

- Use [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke), where [GKE provides the capability](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-cluster) to
  connect to Memorystore if the cluster is configured for it.
- Stay within fully managed Serverless but use a GA version of the
  Serverless VPC Access feature by using [App Engine with Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-memorystore).
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436650/15803365) to connect to Memorystore from Cloud Run using an SSH
  tunnel via GCE.